# Retrieve all prefixes from Graph Database

Tags: namespaces, sparql, prefix

Since I have quite a lot of ontologies with different namespaces and prefixes in my graph datastore and these namespaces change or update over time, I want to retrieve all used namespaces and their prefixes from a given repository in order to create the Prefix-part of my query automatically.

A typical query could be:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> 
PREFIX app: <uri....> 
PREFIX geo: <uri....> 
PREFIX org: <uri....> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX meta: <uri....> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX person: <uri....> 
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
PREFIX incident: <uri....> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?something
WHERE {...}
```

I want to get rid of this long prefix list and either manage it in another ontology or find another way to retrieve all existing prefixes and their URIs for each query.

Answer (score 2):

Short and formally correct answer: prefixes are not part of an RDF graph but syntactic sugar for some serialization languages to make it more compact resp. readable. Some triples stores manage prefixes, but this depends on the triple store indeed.

What I usually do (by using some Java + Jena "magic"):

1. for each URI `u` in the SPARQL query
2. extract the namspace `n` from `u` and get its most commonly used prefix `p` from the prefix.cc lookup service
3. add the prefix mapping `p -> n` to the query
4. print the query

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually that doesn't solve my problem. I know the prefixes used in my graph database repository already but I want to mange them in a central space or any other method since I have around 10+ different queries that share all the same namespace. When I add a namespace to that repository I have to manually update all those separate Prefix lists for each query. And there are other users building their own queries who should not care about this Prefix lists but get them added by default.

Comment: Sorry, but that wasn't clear to from the question. It sound really database specific, so it would be more helpful to know what "graph database repository" you use. And what means "query shares the same namespace"? A query doesn't have a namespace at all.